# Why are we using population symbols ($\sigma^2$, $\mu$, ...) instead of sample symbols ($s^2$, $\bar{x}$, ...) for Random Variables?

Tags: probability, random-variable, sample, population

In my Stats course (can't ask prof, it's an online course), we got to random variables and the notation has changed from using $s^2$, $\bar{x}$, etc...to using what we were initially taught are the symbols used to describe population as opposed to sample; namely $\sigma$, $\mu$, etc...

**Why are we using population symbols when talking about random variables? Do we not use random variables for prediction or inference? And if we do, then aren't those samples?**

I thought I understood that population is the entire data set we're interested in and that inference is done using a sample of that population, because if we already had the entire data set we're interested in there's no inference to be done since we have all the information we need.

It seems to me that if we want to talk about the probability of something happening, we're interested in the behavior of elements we don't currently have in our data set; that should imply that what we currently have is not the population, but a sample.

In this case, why not use population symbols and for example $\frac{1}{n-1}$ instead of $\frac{1}{n}$?

**EDIT**: For example, when talking about the variance of a random variable, the formula given to us is: $$\sigma^2 = Var(X) = E[X^2] - (\mu_x)^2 $$

Comment: Could you edit your post to include a quote where your lecturer uses $\sigma$, $\mu$ etc. in a way you don't understand?

Comment: @StephanKolassa, I edited my post to include an example. Specifically I just don't understand why we're using the greek laters supposedly reserved for describing population tendencies, instead of using sample symbols. I thought any time we are interested in doing prediction/inference we're basically dealing with a sample; so are random variables not used for any of that?

Comment: The formula in your last line is about parameters of a random variable - "population" parameters in your words. It's not about how to *estimate* anything from a sample, nor about sample variance. I think I'm not yet understanding your point.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, if you don't mind I left a comment on Kostia's answer describing what's going through my mind when I see the population symbols. This might help understand my confusion.

Comment: In your example, although $X$ is a random variable, $\operatorname{Var}(X)$ is a *number*: it is a property of that random variable.  Thus, there seems to be no violation of the convention of using lower case Greek letters for properties and other letters for statistics and random variables.  And please beware of the "population" metaphor: although it may be linguistically and conceptually convenient, it simply does not apply in many situations where a *process* or *system* is being studied or where random variables are used to model other things besides finite samples.

Comment: @whuber, but when we are taking Var of a sample, it's still a number; yet, we use $s$ instead of $\sigma$. Why is that? I guess what I'm confused about is why is the random variable itself a population and not a sample? When we take any sample of a population, the sum of the ratios of each element to the whole is also $1$. EDIT: just saw your edited comment. This might be a language thing where I'm taking the english meaning of population too far. It hasn't been precisely defined in our course, besides to say that population is everything we're interested in, and sample is used for prediction.

Comment: Just as English often uses the same word to mean different things--and the listener is assumed to develop the correct understanding from context--so it goes in statistics (and even mathematics). In your example, "Var" is also a *statistic*: a calculation performed on a sample.  ("Mean" also behaves similarly.)  In your question, though, "$X$" was explicitly stipulated to be a *random variable,* not a sample.  Thus "Var" is understood to mean a property of $X$ *qua* random variable: the other sense of "Var" as a statistic just doesn't apply.

Comment: @whuber, I think this makes sense. And you're right with the comment you left under Kostia's answer. I think rigor is what I need because I keep finding myself looking for some structural coherence that I can't find given the lack of rigor in the way the concepts are initially explained to me (not prof's fault, it's supposed to be an intro course, so i think the expectation is that you won't go crazy on your own all the time.). I'll keep in mind what you said and keep learning, I'm sure things will fall in place more and more.

Comment: I have found the [tickets-in-a-box model](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tickets+box) to be helpful in disentangling these related concepts.  Although it is a metaphor for mathematical models of random variables and sampling, it is a remarkably rigorous one.

Comment: @whuber, thank you for the advice, I'll look into that.

Comment: I'd say that it's because mathematical notation is in practice not that rigorous as it pretends at first sight... Moreover, it evolves over time. So there is no single correct notation.

Comment: @Tim, that's a good point. I think after I started doing math, I assumed things were perfectly consistently defined and I could start taking symbols completely literally. I've been confusing myself a lot doing that and also typically trying to map english meaning of words onto mathematical concepts. It's a learning curve and it doesn't help that I'm self-studying almost 100%...but I'm slowly starting to get it and the stackexchange community has been incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of a set of values a random variable can take (called sample space) as a population. For example, if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then the underlying population (sample space) is the set of all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is essentially a sampling law: it describes how sample are obtained from the population. If $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is a sample form $\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then the sample mean $\bar{x}$ is an approximation of the "theoretical" mean $\mu$.

> Do we not use random variables for prediction or inference?

Yes, we do use random variable for prediction and inference, but this statement is too general. More precisely, in the context of statistical inference, we use random variable to model the variability observed in the data.

Comment: I guess my confusion is that I've come to associate (perhaps erroneously) the idea of doing inference and predictions with using a sample instead of a population. So in my mind it goes something like "Ok, we're using probability so obviously we want to make predictions about future behavior and likelihood of something happening. Therefore we're using a sample since we're interested in elements no currently in our data set. So...why are we using population symbols? Why is this a population?"

Comment: I realize you're trying to give intuitive, informal explanations, but equating sample spaces, populations, and random variables on the one hand, and distributions and "sampling laws" on the other seems to ignore some of the distinctions the OP is attempting to understand.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I agree with your comment. But in this question I simply don't know how to provide intuitive explanation without sacrificing some rigor. I think at this level, it is ok to think of sample space as population, etc.

Comment: @jeremyradcliff You may find Section 6 from the following notes useful. http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04929v1.pdf Please let me know if this helps. If not I will try my best to provide further explanations.

Comment: From comments posted by the OP, my impression is that rigor is exactly what he needs.  He seems to be suffering from a lack of it.  But--to anticipate a possible objection--note that "rigor" does not necessarily mean "couched in opaque mathematical notation."  It's possible to be rigorous, clear, and intuitive at the same time.

Comment: @Kostia, thank you for the link, I think this is what I need because a ton of stuff is getting thrown at us non-formally and I'm getting stuck and hung up on the english words and trying (and failing) to map the words' meanings onto the math concepts.

Comment: @whuber I got the source of confusion differently :) This is how I understood it. They discussed survey sampling (or similar topic), where there is a population $x_1,\ldots,x_N$ and a random sample from population $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. Discussing random sample, they used "sample symbols" $\bar{X}, s^2$, etc. Then they moved to random variables and notations suddenly changed to $\mu, \sigma^2$ (previously used for population parameters), instead of "expected" $\bar{X}, s^2$, etc.